# What is the correct way to center a \tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

What is the correct way to cause a `\tikzpicture` to be centered?  By default it appears to be aligned with the left margin.

Comment: I preffer to put 
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
in the preamble, so that every tikzpicture is centered =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Also covered in my answer to the linked question.

Comment: I know =) Exelent answer, that is why I posted it as a comment not as an answer. I guess this question can be closed as Jake said, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Using `adjustbox` package: `\begin{adjustbox}{center}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{adjustbox}`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\tikz
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, just want to share a sublety: I applied this solution and I got the following error: "There's no line here to end." I found the error was caused by using line-breaking (//) within an edge label. I just removed the line-breaking and all worked well.

Comment: The `figure` environment doesn't just center the `tikzpicture`, it also adds a caption and some vertical spacing, which may not be desired.

Answer (score 123):

When the picture doesn't need to be put in a figure (i.e. when it doesn't need a caption), I use

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  ....
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: In my case the picture is too wide, so it breaks the right margin. Is there a way to make it break the left and right margins equally?

Answer (score 8):

`\hbox to \hsize{\hfil{Anything}\hfil}`