# Center every tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, pgfkeys

I want every tikzpicture to be centered in my document but want to be able to deactivate this feature locally. For example:

```
%Pseudocode...
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  thalign=center
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%%Centered - should be equivalent to a normal tikzpicture enclosed in a center environment
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[thalign=left]
%%Not centered
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I to this?

In particular I am interested of how to do it with keys as in my pseudocode above.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

I would define a new environment using the answer of [What is the correct way to center a \tikzpicture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62495/114090):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}
{\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}}
{\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ctikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{ctikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the centered desired figure inside a centered paragraph: `{\par\centering...\par}` and leave the others as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{\par\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%Centered - should be equivalent to a normal tikzpicture enclosed in a center environment
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}\par}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%%Not centered
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's clear, but doesn't answer my question. The point is that I want a global key as described in my pseudocode above. hzhr's answer does (almost) what I want, but without a key syntax.

Comment: That key doesn't exist. A tikzpicture is like any other character. How do you force 'a' to be in the center of a line?

Comment: @Maybe it could be implemented with a pre and post environment hook...